# Delphi: TRichEdit Text in non-default non-Unicode system language as String (ANSI)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, richedit, input-language

**So here's the setup:**

1. Make a new Delphi 7 application with a TRichEdit control on it. We are talking non-Unicode applications here.
2. Install a new Input language in Windows' Regional and Language Options, **that has a different encoding from the encoding of your [*default Language for non-Unicode programs*](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_select_language_version.mspx?mfr=true)** - for example Greek.
3. Add a button in the application, and in its `OnClick` handler add `Button1.Caption := RichEdit1.Text;`, and set its `Font.Charset` to the charset of the input language you just installed (`GREEK_CHARSET` if we stick to this example).
4. Run the application, switch to your new (Greek) input language, type a few letters in the RichEdit and press the button - the button's caption now has `????` symbols instead of Greek characters.
5. Now, if you set your *default Language for non-Unicode programs* to Greek (Windows restart required), this problem would disappear - greek characters would appear properly. Set your *default Language for non-Unicode programs* back to what it was before and the problem is there again.

So I would guess that TRichEdit works with Unicode internally, as changing its Font.Charset value never changes anything - the RichEdit accepts any installed Input language properly, and if you have installed two different non-latin languages which use different character sets (Greek /`GREEK_CHARSET`/ and Russian /`RUSSIAN_CHARSET`/ for example) it would accept them both without changing its Font.Charset.

I would also guess that when you get the `.Text` (or `.Lines[i]`) value of the TRichEdit, it converts its internal Unicode text to ANSI, based on the Windws' *default Language for non-Unicode programs*.

Further more, assigning the `.Text` value to a WideString or a UnicodeString also doesn't work properly (the text is once again in `????` instead of the proper characters), it's not only when you assign it to a String (AnsiString).

**So here's the question:**

I want to be able to convert the text of a RichEdit to a String (ANSI) properly, based on a character set of my choosing instead of the system's *default Language for non-Unicode programs*. How can I do that? I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve third party components, but, of course, if not possible - anything would do.

Thanks!

P.S.: Switching to Delphi 2009 or later is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send the underlying rich edit window the [`EM_GETTEXTEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb774192.aspx) message. You pass a [`GETTEXTEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb787913.aspx) struct which specifies the code page.

So, something like this would pull the text out into a UTF-16 encoded `WideString`:

```
function GetRichEditText(RichEdit: TRichEdit): WideString;
var
  GetTextLengthEx: TGetTextLengthEx;
  GetTextEx: TGetTextEx;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  GetTextLengthEx.flags := GTL_DEFAULT;
  GetTextLengthEx.codepage := 1200;
  Len := SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX, 
    WPARAM(@GetTextLengthEx), 0);
  if Len=E_INVALIDARG then
    raise Exception.Create('EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX failed');
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  if Len=0 then
    exit;
  GetTextEx.cb := (Length(Result)+1)*SizeOf(WideChar);
  GetTextEx.flags := GTL_DEFAULT;
  GetTextEx.codepage := 1200;
  GetTextEx.lpDefaultChar := nil;
  GetTextEx.lpUsedDefChar := nil;
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_GETTEXTEX, WPARAM(@GetTextEx), 
    LPARAM(PWideChar(Result)));
end;
```

You can then convert that UTF-16 string to whatever code page you like. If you'd rather pull it out in a specific code page directly, then do it like this:

```
function GetRichEditText(RichEdit: TRichEdit; AnsiCodePage: UINT): AnsiString;
var
  GetTextLengthEx: TGetTextLengthEx;
  GetTextEx: TGetTextEx;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  GetTextLengthEx.flags := GTL_DEFAULT;
  GetTextLengthEx.codepage := AnsiCodePage;
  Len := SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX, 
    WPARAM(@GetTextLengthEx), 0);
  if Len=E_INVALIDARG then
    raise Exception.Create('EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX failed');
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  if Len=0 then
    exit;
  GetTextEx.cb := (Length(Result)+1)*SizeOf(AnsiChar);
  GetTextEx.flags := GTL_DEFAULT;
  GetTextEx.codepage := AnsiCodePage;
  GetTextEx.lpDefaultChar := nil;
  GetTextEx.lpUsedDefChar := nil;
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_GETTEXTEX, WPARAM(@GetTextEx), 
    LPARAM(PWideChar(Result)));
end;
```

Comment: @TLama Are you sure that `RICHEDIT` does not support Unicode?

Comment: By [`this description`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Rich_Edit_Version_1.0) at least editing shouldn't support Unicode, but I haven't verified this.

Comment: @TLama Your link seems to state this for RichEdit control 1.0, i.e. the one included in Windows 98/Me, AFAIR. Good old days... from my experiment, the RichEdit component is Unicode since a lot of time.

Comment: +1 Note that the function returning an AnsiString will work with Delphi < 2009, but with Unicode version of Delphi, it may be confusing, since AnsiString has the system-wide code page of Non-Unicode applications settings. This is not the case for Delphi 7, so the answer is perfect for what the OP asked. Nice!

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Yes, this was written with pre-Unicode Delphi in mind. I guess in Unicode Delphi you'd return `RawByteString`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Thanks! That works like a charm! Now I also need to do the opposite - set the RichEdit text (the `????` are there again if I simply use the `.Text` property). I was thinking it would be as simple as using `EM_SETTEXTEX`, however this message and the `SETTEXTEX` structure are defined in RichEdit v.3, and my Delphi 7 RichEdit unit is v.2.0... Is there another way to set the RichEdit text properly, or do I HAVE to use RichEdit v.3? If I have to use RichEdit v.3, is it compatible with Delphi 7? Sorry if those are dumb questions, I'm not that advanced yet. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `EM_SETTEXTEX`. It looks so similar to `EM_GETTEXTEX` that it seems hard to imagine that your control handles one and not the other.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I tried it. It IS hard to imagine, but nonetheless `EM_SETTEXTEX` is defined in RichEdit v.3, and `EM_GETTEXTEX` is defined in RichEdit v.2. Here's the link: [`EM_SETTEXTEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774284(v=vs.85).aspx) - it says Rich Edit 3.0. I checked the code of my RichEdit unit, it's v.2.0, it has EM_GETTEXTEX and GETTEXTEX, but not EM_SETTEXTEX and SETTEXTEX. What should I do, any advice?

Comment: I should think you can do it with `EM_STREAMIN` passing `SF_TEXT or SF_UNICODE`. You'd need to convert from your ANSI code page to UTF-16, and then send that wide text.

Comment: You could also try `EM_SETTEXTEX`. You'd need to define it, and the struct. The versions of rich edit seem very hard to fathom.

Comment: Thanks, @David - here's what I came up with:
`procedure SetRichEditText(RichEdit: TRichEdit; Text: String; AnsiCodePage: UINT);
const
  EM_SETTEXTEX = WM_USER + 97;
type
  _settextex = packed record
    flags: DWORD;
    codepage: UINT;
  end;
  SETTEXTEX = _settextex;
  TSetTextEx = _settextex;
var
  TheSetTextEx: TSetTextEx;
begin
  TheSetTextEx.flags := GTL_DEFAULT;
  TheSetTextEx.codepage := AnsiCodePage;
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_SETTEXTEX, WPARAM(@TheSetTextEx), LPARAM(PWideChar(Text)));
end;`
Note that this requires Win 2k or later to work (won't work on Win 98).

Comment: Just one more note - it should be `LPARAM(PChar(Result))` in `GetRichEditText` and `LPARAM(PChar(Text))` in `SetRichEditText` (typecast to PChar instead of to PWideChar), otherwise the compiler complains for `Suspicious typecast of String to PWideChar`, although everything works correctly anyway.